# MediaRecorder audiochunks includes previous recording

Tags: javascript, blob, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I've a piece of code for recording audio only and sending it to my server everytime a silence is registered.

This works fine for the first recording.

Every recording following afterwards attaches the previous recording to the new recording.

Example:

> Audio1: Hello, this is sentence 1.
>
> Audio2: Hello, this is sentence 1. Hello, this is sentence 2.
>
> Audio3: Hello, this is sentence1. Hello, this is sentence 2. Hello,
> this is sentence 3.

The recordings never start from scratch.

My code so far simplified:

```js
var audioChunks = [];

function SendBlobToServer(blob) {
  //jquery post-request to server
}

function detectSilence(
  stream,
  onSoundEnd = _ => {},
  onSoundStart = _ => {},
  silence_delay = 500,
  min_decibels = -80
) {
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
  const streamNode = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  streamNode.connect(analyser);
  analyser.minDecibels = min_decibels;

  const data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); // will hold our data
  let silence_start = performance.now();
  let triggered = false; // trigger only once per silence event

  function loop(time) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop); // we'll loop every 60th of a second to check
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data); // get current data
    if (data.some(v => v)) { // if there is data above the given db limit
      if (triggered) {
        triggered = false;
        onSoundStart();
      }
      silence_start = time; // set it to now
    }
    if (!triggered && time - silence_start > silence_delay) {
      onSoundEnd();
      triggered = true;
    }
  }
  loop();
}

function onSilence() {
  console.log('silence');
  window.recorder.requestData();
}

function onSpeak() {
  console.log('speaking');
}

const ReadBlobContent = blob => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
  });
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {
  window.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  window.recorder.onstart = function(e) {
    console.log("window.recorder.onstart");
    detectSilence(stream, onSilence, onSpeak);
  };

  window.recorder.onstop = function(e) {
    console.log("window.recorder.onstop");
  };

  window.recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
    if (window.recorder.state === "recording") {
      let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
        type: 'audio/mpeg-3'
      });

      ReadBlobContent(blob).then(res => SendBlobToServer(res.split(',')[1]));
    }
  };

  window.recorder.start();
  // do something else with the stream
}).catch(console.error);
```

I tried doing `audioChunks = []` at the last line of`SendBlobToServer()`, but that
corrupts the blob file of the next sentence making the audio unplayable.

How do I clear the `audiochunks` array the correct way without having to rely on using `recorder.start()` and `recorder.stop()` with every spoken sentence. I want to keep my recording state and audio stream going while I clear the `audiochunks`.